# Firebase Admin: Is it necessary to check if uid decoded on the server (based on client ID token) matches the uid from the client?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

In my server I'm accessing user-specific data by passing a Firebase `uid` as a parameter (i.e. `GET /users/:uid`). I'm also generating an ID token from the Firebase client and decoding that token on the server to get the `uid`. I then check that these two `uid`s are the same.

Based on how Firebase handles tokens, is this necessary? Or can Firebase effectively determine that a request's `uid` parameter (generated using `Auth.auth().getUserId` and a token (generated using `Auth.auth().generateIdToken()`) didn't originate from the same user?

Note: I'm not using a Firebase database so I don't have the additional security from database permissions.

Comment: It's hard to know what exactly to tell you without a more explicit look at your code. Can you try to add a minimal code sample to this question that shows what you're currently doing and what you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin docs recommend the following approach to verify the currently signed-in user on the server.

> If your Firebase client app communicates with a custom backend server, you might need to identify the currently signed-in user on that server. To do so securely, after a successful sign-in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the `uid` from it. You can use the `uid` transmitted in this way to securely identify the currently signed-in user on your server.

Therefore, you only need to get the user's ID token on the client and send it to the server using `HTTPS`. This is sufficient to securely verify the user's identity.

### Server Code (node.js)

```
// idToken comes from the client app
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

See Firebase Admin Docs: [**Verify ID Tokens**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)